# Bathroom light won’t turn off

Tags: electrical

Fitting a new ceiling light and it won’t turn off. Coming from the ceiling I have 4 red wires and 2 black and an earth however the light unit doesn’t have anywhere for this to go.
It turns on but won’t switch off.

Comment: With the power off, take good, clear, focused pictures of the wiring at the light and the switch that controls it, then [edit] these into your question. That will help us help you figure out what's going on. Also, please indicate where in the world you live, as wiring codes vary as does the purpose indicated by wire color.

Comment: Presumably you are in older housing stock in the UK, or a former Commonwealth country, based on the colors?

Comment: Most likely, you have connected the incoming live straight to the lamp, without it going through the switch first.  But pictured would really help.